Can I import a 3D cad model as an area target in Vuforia?
vuforia's area targets, do they have to be scanned areas?
can a 3d cad model of a building be used as an area target in unity?
if yes, how can I implement it in unity vuforia?
if no, can i make a scan with a simple android device phone?
thanks
downloaded vudoria area target generator but i see i can only import scans (matterport and e57 data files).

No, CAD models cannot be used as AreaTargets. The AreaTarget localization works on data extracted from the RGB images part the input scan. You could try to create a Vuforia ModelTarget though which is designed to work with CAD models https://developer.vuforia.com/library/objects/model-targets

I see.
I tried to overcome this issue with cloudcompare: i convert a mesh model to point cloud and then tried to import the e57 file to ATG.  but no luck...
it got an error:  [   FAIL  ] E57 shall contain one or more Image2D structures that have either 'sphericalRepresentation' field or 'pinholeRepresentation' field."
is there any way to bypass this?  or is this the wrong approach anyway?   because a 'recent' scan of the area has better iamge tracing 'marks' for the vuforia to work than a clean 3d model?

No there is no way to bypass it. Any scan must have the RGB image data (either in pinhole or spherical representation). Indeed this is the wrong approach. I guess that your CAD model does not provide a photorealistic representation of the building appearance. Area Targets are designed to work with real images, while Model Targets can work with geometry-only (non photorealistic) representations typically available in CAD models.
